# Splitting String with Multiple Delimiters in a Particular Order

Tags: python, string, split

I am dealing with a type of ASCII file where there are effectively 4 columns of data and the each row is assigned to a line in the file. Below is an example of a row of data from this file

```
'STOP.F 11966.0000:STOP DEPTH'
```

The data is  always structured so that the delimiter between the first and second column is a period, the delimiter between the second and third column is a space and the delimiter between the third and fourth column is a colon.

Ideally, I would like to find a way to return the following result from the string above

```
['STOP', 'F', '11966.0000', 'STOP DEPTH']
```

I tried using a regular expression with the period, space and colon as delimiters, but it breaks down (see example below) because I don't know how to specify the specific order in which to split the string, and I don't know if there is a way to specify the maximum number of splits per delimiter right in the regular expression itself. I want it to split the delimiters in the specific order and each delimiter a maximum of 1 time.

```
import re
line = 'STOP.F 11966.0000:STOP DEPTH'
re.split("[. :]", line)
>>> ['STOP', 'F', '11966', '0000', 'STOP', 'DEPTH']
```

Any suggestions on a tidy way to do this?

Comment: This expression will divide the line in the 4 capturing groups. ^(.+)\.(.+) (.+):(.+)$ I am not sure how you implement it in python

Comment: Applying the regex supplied by @Juan , this seems to do the trick: `re.split("(.+)\.(.+) (.+):(.+)", line)[1:5]`

Answer (score 1):

This may work. Credit to [Juan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225960/juan)

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^(.+)\.(.+) (.+):(.+)$')
line = 'STOP.F 11966.0000:STOP DEPTH'
pattern.search(line).groups()
Out[6]: ('STOP', 'F', '11966.0000', 'STOP DEPTH')
```

Answer (score 0):

**`re.split()`** solution with specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s = 'STOP.F 11966.0000:STOP DEPTH'
result = re.split(r'(?<=^[^.]+)\.|(?<=^[^ ]+) |:', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['STOP', 'F', '11966.0000', 'STOP DEPTH']
```

Comment: This exact code throws me the following error in python 3.6.2: `sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern` I was trying to compare execution time compiling the pattern first.